# Why do alt-codes skip me to a new line in Word?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, alt-code

If I try to type an alt-code that goes "ALT-02**," then I cannot finish writing the alt-code, because the cursor will move to the beginning of the next line. I googled "alt 02 skips to next line," but found no relevant results. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you typing? The string above looks a bit scrambled.

Comment: I just mean to say any alt code whose first two characters needed to type are 0 and 2, like "alt-0225" for á.

Comment: I cannot duplicate the problem. Perhaps Office needs to be repaired from Control Panel > Programs and Features.

Comment: You need to enter the numeric portion from the Number Pad. It won't work from the standard number keys.

Comment: I am using the numpad.